# jQuery Removing specific text from an text of my website

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the text `"code":"` and the " at the end of code here from an element in my website. I want the rest of the text to remain there. How can I achieve that with jQuery? Thank you.

The text

```
"code":"code here"
```

I want it to just be:

```
code here
```

Comment: Be more specific, that looks more like part of a JSON string or javascript object, than something you'd have in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

1. store your text in some temp var

   `var tmp  = $('your_dom_selector').html();`
2. remove the first part

   `tmp = tmp.replace('"code: "','');`
3. Replace it without the last character in your element

   `$('your_dom_selector').empty().append(tmp.substring(0, tmp.length-1));`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your element is like this

```
<p id="pp">"code":"code here"</p>
```

then you can use this code

```
 $().ready(function(){
    var texts=$("#pp").html();
    var ar=texts.split('":"');
    alert(ar[1].slice(0,-1));

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's weird what you are trying to accomplish, but another way you can do it is like this:

```
var element = $('domSelector'),
    text = element.html(),
    strippedText = text.substring(text.indexOf('"code here"') + 1, text.length - 1);

console.log(stripedText);

element.html(stripedText);
```

Hope this helps!